# Order in Python for loop (LeetCode 219 Contains Duplicate II)

Tags: python, python-3.x

https://goodtecher.com/leetcode-219-contains-duplicate-ii/

In this Python solution, why does `visited[nums[i]] = i` have to come after the if condition? I don't understand why the code wouldn't work if the order is reversed like this:

```
    visited = {}
    
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        visited[nums[i]] = i        
        if nums[i] in visited and abs(i - visited[nums[i]]) <= k:
            return True
        
    return False
```

I would appreciate an explanation as well as some sources to help me understand what I don't understand about how order works in Python loops. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem presented -:**

The code presented above in the OP, after thorough investigation seems to be in an attempt to solve a problem wherein, the code returns `true` if there exists two distinct indices `i` and `j` in a list of numbers `nums`, such that -:

- `nums[i] == nums[j]`
- `abs(i - j) <= k`

Also, the constraints stated in the link provided are -:

- `1 <= nums.length <= 10^5`
- `-10^9 <= nums[i] <= 10^9`
- `0 <= k <= 10^5` [k is thus given to always be positive for any given testcase]

---

**Explanation of the solution -:**

Now, the code given as a solution tries to solve this problem, by declaring a dictionary `visited`, and looping using a for loop from 0 to the length of the given list of numbers[`nums`]. Every iteration of the loop it considers the loop variable `i` to be the index `i` as stated in the problem, and tries to fetch the value of the key `nums[i]` and use that as the index `j`, given that `nums[i]` is already a key in visited, since one of the problem's condition is to check for `nums[i] == nums[j]`, and thus -:

`if nums[i] in visited and abs(i - visited[nums[i]]) <= k:`

Structure of the visited dictionary as pseudo code -:

`{nums[k] : k}` or `{value_at_some_index_k : index_k}`

Also, Incase the value for `nums[i]`, does not already exist as a key in the `visited` dictionary, it adds it to the dictionary as a key, but in such a case the if statement is not invoked, since it precedes the assignment. This also answers the question posed, which is that why exactly is there a need for the if statement to precede the assignment, in the loop order.

`visited[nums[i]] = i`

---

**The reason assigning before the if statement does not work -:**

Note that the above statement, only acts as a way to register this value as a key for the loop's future iterations(if any), to check for a match.

If the assignment was to precede the if statement, then the if statement would've always returned true[given that k >= 0], since -:

- `i = 0, 1, 2...`
- `j = visited[nums[i]]`, and `visited[nums[i]] = i`, due to assignment so, `j = i`
- `abs(i - j) = abs(i - i) = abs(0) = 0` and `k >= 0` is given.

---

Also here is a simpler version of the same code, to make it feel more relatable -:

```
visited = {} # declare the visited dict, format -: {nums[k] : k} for some index k

for i in range(len(nums)): # loop with i as loop variable over the range of indexes for nums
    if nums[i] in visited :
        # since visited[nums[i]] is the value of the key and is equal to j, 
        # that means the key must be nums[j], so nums[i] == nums[j] is already satisfied.
        j = visited[nums[i]] # Assigning this to j, to make it more easier to related with the problem.
        if abs(i - j) <= k: # check for the condition demanded in the problem.
            return True # return true if the conditions are met.
    visited[nums[i]] = i # Incase the value doesn't already exist, add it to the dict.
    continue # continue the loop
    
return False
```